# How do we identify an address as a valid MAC address

Tags: mac-address

If 000.a83.b1c.08e is a valid MAC address then why is 123.123.123.123 not a valid address?
Also if how do we identify its 32 bit long or 48 bit long

Comment: An ethernet MAC is 48bits. IPv4 addresses are 32bits. They are two **completely** different things. Anything asking for a MAC will almost certainly be expecting hex input.

Comment: @Ricky how do we know its 32 bit pls explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard notation for 48-bit MAC addresses is with 12 hexadecimal digits (0-9,a-f), often grouped in two, four, or six, rarely three.

32-bit IPv4 addresses are usually written as four decimal octets, 0-255 each, separated by dots.

`123.123.123.123` looks very much like an IPv4 address, but could actually be interpreted as a MAC address as well (hexadecimal, in groups of three), `12-31-23-12-31-23` in IEEE notation. However, 1**2**... indicates a locally-administered address (the U/L bit is set) which might not be accepted in many environments.

Similarly, any odd value in the second digit would indicate a group address (I/G bit set) which cannot be used as a source address in general. `0`, `4`, `8`, or `c` in the second hex digit would indicate a valid, global, unicast address.

Comment: thank you...if you have any online material which contains indetail info request you to please share

Comment: Sorry, resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here but you might want to check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Addressing as primers.